# Expandable listview item height with another listview inside

Tags: android, listview, height, expandable

I have an ExpandableListView, where every group has one child. Every child is another ListView with different number of rows. There is a problem with ExpandableListView item height in expanded condition, it's not wraping to child ListView content. I just can set a concrete height value in child listview layout. But i want to get an ExpandableListView automatically wrap every child. Is it possible?

`getChildView(`) from my `ExpandableListAdapter`:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if( convertView == null ) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.anit_object_data, parent, false );
    }
    ListView lv = (ListView)convertView.findViewById( R.id.listData );
    List<ListData> valuesList = getItems().get(groupPosition).getListData( getContext() );
    ListDataAdapter adapter = new ListDataAdapter( getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valuesList );
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return convertView;
}
```

XML for child ListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id = "@+id/listHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listData"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I was trying to measure child ListView height in getChildView() of adapter, but ExpandableListView expanded item height is still incorrect.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if( convertView == null ) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.anit_object_data, parent, false );
    }
    ListView lv = (ListView)convertView.findViewById( R.id.listData );
    List<ListData> valuesList = getItems().get(groupPosition).getListData( getContext() );
    ListDataAdapter adapter = new ListDataAdapter( getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valuesList );
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.measure( MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED );
    convertView.getLayoutParams().height = lv.getMeasuredHeight();

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the `ExpandableListview` to collapse every child ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, i don't have problems with collapsed childs.

Comment: Try this:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren.htm

Answer (score 1):

well，I have tried your mind that the group child view was a listview. But the result was not good. Because the height of the childview(listview) was hard to measure.So I changed the solution as the normal way:  the child view was just an item that is just like a listview's item. So that we override the getChildView() method as well.

Answer (score 1):

You don`t need a listview inside the expandablelist, it`s control yourself the inflate of childs positions, all you have be is pass other list and take the childposition